# Debugging on chrome for Angular8 project stopped working

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using `Angular8` framework with `typescript` language, `Vs code` as an editor, and `Chrome` as browser. I did debugging on `Chrome` and it was working fine, today onwards it stopped debugging.
Focus comes on the debugger but on mouse over - there is no value to display:
[image]

Comment: Try restarting the VS Code and Chrome.

Comment: I tried it no success.

Comment: You sould have folder '.' (dot) in folder treeView with your 'ts' files.  Try to set breaks there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm facing the same issue. It seems to be a bug of the newest version of Chrome. As we, other users are experiencing that bug. More details [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/22882968?hl=en).

I suggest you to try debugging in `Canary` or in `Chromium`, maybe is a problem they've already fixed in the not-sable versions that has not been released yet.

Comment: Thanks you are right, the issue is related to chrome version, working fine on Canary

Comment: Thank you too, I didn't try on Canary but glad you said that it works fine on that version.